# Make transparent area with specific form

Tags: css, styled-components

I try to make this area transparent like in design, using mask-image. But I couldn’t do it anymore. Can someone help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code? or you need help related to the syntax?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far. For a start, I would suggest you play around with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path, or else you can just create that mask inside Photoshop and then use it.